# How to write encode h264 to a byte array other than a file

Tags: windows, media, encode, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I'm using a MSDN tutorial to encode RAW RGB32 frame to an h264 videon this first part works without any problem. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff819477%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

But, there is one think that i can do : I just want to write the output encoded video to a BYTE array other than the file, i have read about 400 different web pages and all the Media Foundation documentation, but i don't see how to do that !!

I have try many different way, life using MFCreateTempFile and work with the IMFByteStream but there is nothing to do !

After i have try with it : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms698913%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
But my buffer is empty !

Please help me !! I'm losing my eyes !!

Answer (score 0):

[H.264 Video Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is an MFT, that is it exposes [IMFTransform interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms696260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and does not necessarily need to participate in a session. You can instantiate it standalone, set it up and get raw H.264 encoded data from its `ProcessOutput` method.

Comment: I'm reading the documentation and it seems to work like the sinkwriter : with processInput and processOut with wich i can read the buffered output like you say ! Now i need to find a fast RGB to YUV implementation !! Thanks for your fast response !